# Highcharts logarithmic scale with very small numbers

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I'm using this function to display negative values on logarithmic scale. Everything works fine except if I put very small numbers like :

[8, 6.986e-8],[14.947368421052632, 1.705e-7],[21.894736842105264, 3.299e-7],[28.842105263157897, 5.606e-7],[35.78947368421053, 8.765e-7],[42.73684210526316, 0.000001292]

In this case y-axis won't be transfer to logaritmic. I don't have deep understanding of prototyping inner functions of highcharts. Highcharts version is 6.1.2.

```
// Pass error messages
H.Axis.prototype.allowNegativeLog = true;

// Override conversions
H.Axis.prototype.log2lin = function (num) {
    var isNegative = num < 0,
        adjustedNum = Math.abs(num),
        result;
    if (adjustedNum < 10) {
        adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
    }
    result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
    return isNegative ? -result : result;
};
H.Axis.prototype.lin2log = function (num) {
    var isNegative = num < 0,
        absNum = Math.abs(num),
        result = Math.pow(10, absNum);
    if (result < 10) {
        result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
    }
    return isNegative ? -result : result;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9oLpayw1/ (need to put data)

Comment: Hi DuFuS, I'm not quite sure how you want your method to work, but your problem can be related with `Highcharts.correctFloat` method. By default it rounds the number to the 14th decimal place. You can try to overwrite this method. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.correctFloat

Comment: Thank you, but as I said I have poor understanding of prototyping and overwriting inner functions so exact code would help me. If you be so nice. I would appreciate it. Thx

Comment: You can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4ca2px3b/

Comment: Please let me know if it helped.